# how to use data from for in html using MapView in nativescript

Tags: angular, for-loop, nativescript

From this function I get data:

```
this.spots.spotsnerby().subscribe(
        spot => {
            this.spot = spot;
            for (let j = 0; j < this.spot.features.length; j++) {
                let ii = this.spot.features[j];
               console.log(ii.properties.stato_stallo);
        });



 onMarkerSelect(arg) {
          console.log('id', id);
    }
```

html

```
<MapView class="map" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" markerSelect)="onMarkerSelect($event)"></MapView>
```

How to select `ii.properties.stato_stallo` from html code?

Can you ask me any idea please?

Comment: If spotsnerby is an Observable / Subject, you may simply use async pipe in HTML template, loop through for each index and access the properties.

Comment: Please, can you write an example please?